# Cannot find ADO.Net in VS2022 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net, scaffolding

I've recently started using VS2022 Community Edition Version 17.4.4 after using VS2017 Enterprise Edition for many years. I've started a new project after selecting ASP.Net Core Web App using MVC. After creating the project, I used Nuget to import the MS.EntityFramwork packages I need and the went to add a new item to select ADO.Net from my DB for my Entity Framework. However, as you can see from the screenshot below the packages are there but ADO.Net is not.

[image]

Although I cannot find ADO.Net I can select Scaffolding if I want to and something tells me that is the only option available to me. I've used this process of adding Entity Framework many times and I think it's no coincidence that it isn't available after updating my Visual Studio. Can someone please confirm this is my only option to work with my SQL database or is there something I'm missing in order to access ADO.Net.

Comment: The tooling is only available in .NET Framework projects  not .net (Core,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.Net only works with .Net Framework. You can pay attention to see what your framework version is. If it is .Net XXX, it should be that you have created the wrong project, and the type of project you should create is ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework).

If following the methods above doesn't work, please speak up.